# How to take daily backup of database?

Tags: backup, mysql, scheduled

Hey I am using mysql in ubuntu along with 15 more ppl who also has root privilege. 
I am afraid they might accidentally tamper with the database, so I want to take a daily and hourly incremental backup of the database, and its privileges.

Can anyone help me with a solution?

Note: I can cron mysqldump, but I need to do svn kind of thing so that I can see the changes, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The repository contains an application for taking backups: `automysqlbackup`. Backups are made from the whole database, including privileges, and placed in `/var/lib/automysqlbackup/`. This can be changed in `/etc/default/automysqlbackup`.

About the versioning part, the repository only grows in size. A better solution might be diffing two backups. Such a script can be setup using the `POSTBACKUP` hook (see the bottom of `/etc/default/automysqlbackup`).

You might also be interested in a similar question on Serverfault: [Incremental MySQL Backup using Subversion](https://serverfault.com/q/48170/51929)